# Create virtual side screen in Windows 7

Tags: desktop, virtual-desktop

I am trying to set up a virtual side screen in Windows 7, like in Ubuntu where you can go to the left or right and have another desktop. Is there freeware that will accomplish this for me? Or options already built in to Win7 that I have to enable?

The reason I am doing this is to put a VNC viewer window on that second screen. At my desk, I have my ipod to the left of my laptop docked in my ihome. I can control the Ipod through a VNC viewer over wireless. I want to have the feel of moving my mouse left over to my ipod, simulating my ipod as a second screen that my mouse can almost move on to.

**Update:** I've found my solution. [Deskhedron](http://tokyodownstairs.blogspot.com/2008/10/deskhedron.html) is completely free, and has as much functionality as I need. Works very well. Intended for Xp, but I'm running it on win7 with no compatibility enabled and it runs well.

Comment: What you are describing in Ubuntu is the virtual desktop manager, but it sounds like what you are trying to accomplish is more like a virtual second monitor.  I'm not sure if the two concepts are compatible. But who knows, this is SuperUser after all. Someone may have the answer you need. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my solution. [Deskhedron](http://tokyodownstairs.blogspot.com/2008/10/deskhedron.html) is completely free, and has as much functionality as I need. Works very well. Intended for Xp, but I'm running it on win7 with no compatibility enabled and it runs well.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple choices:

1. [DeskSpace](http://www.otakusoftware.com/deskspace/)
2. [Virtual Desktop Manager](http://www.codeplex.com/vdm)
3. [Crystal Desktop](http://www.cdesktop.brightek-soft.com/)

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you can run it fluidly, DeskSpace really helps with the whole visualising thing.

Comment: Is there an alternative similar to DeskSpace that is freeware?